# Notification Observer is not catching the post

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a split view controller, and the child masterView is attempting to send out a post notification under certain conditions in the 'viewDidAppear' method.  However, the Observer that is located in the parent isn't ever being triggered.

Here is the observer code, implemented inside the viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(customerSearchStatusIsSelected:) name:@"CUSTOMER_ORDER_DID_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
```

and this is the post I have in the child masterView's viewDidAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CUSTOMER_ORDER_DID_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_tableData forKey:@"data"]];
```

this is my selector method header

```
-(void)customerSearchStatusIsSelected:(NSNotification *)data
{
   //some code
}
```

The childMasterView definitely sends out the post, but the selector I want the observer to call never gets called.  What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to move your notification registration code from `-viewDidLoad:` to `-init` method?

Comment: just tried that, no effect

Comment: ok, i moved the observer to the viewDidAppear method and that seemed to work.  I have no idea what the difference would be....

Comment: the setup and loading of the controller is not fully loaded to add a observer to a controller to it it must initialised

Answer (score 2):

solution: needed to move the observer from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear ... for whatever reason...